# How to logrotate custom log file on system boot

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate

I need to logrotate on system boot. I created a custom config for logrotate to zip the file. The solution with @reboot does not work.

In root crontable I have something like this:

```
@reboot --force /etc/logrotate.conf
```

but it doesn't work. I am working on Debian 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean crontab when you say 'crontable', in which case your formatting is just incorrect. Per the crontab man page ([1](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)) :

```
These special time specification "nicknames" are supported, 
which replace the 5 initial time and date fields, and are prefixed by the '@' character:

@reboot    :    Run once after reboot.
```

The `@reboot` nickname only replaces the 5 time/date fields; you still need to follow the rules on how commands are formatted in crontab (again, from the manpages):

`<date fields> <user to run command as> <command to run>`

E.g.,

`30 12 * 8 * root touch /tmp/file`

So if you want to use the `@reboot` nickname, all you should be replacing are the five time/date fields at the beginning of the string, e.g.

`@reboot root touch /tmp/file`